# Cannot repeatedly F5-deploy an OWIN Service Fabric application in VS 2015 RC

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an application (in my case, with two stateless services following the OWIN+Web API tutorial, and leaving each instance count at 1)
2. F5-deploy to start the application -- everything works, and I can see the application in the Service Fabric Explorer
3. Shift-F5 in VS 2015 (RC) to stop debugging -- the application continues to run in Service Fabric Explorer
4. F5-deploy again -- an exception occurs in each stateless service, as follows:

> ```
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146232828
>   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>        at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>        at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>        at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>        at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(IAppBuilder builder)
>        at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
>        at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(String url, Action`1 startup)
>        at Infrastructure.OwinCommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApiSF\Infrastructure\OwinCommunicationListener.cs:line 47
>        at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.StatelessServiceBase.<OpenCommunicationListenerAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>   InnerException: 
>        ErrorCode=5
>        HResult=-2147467259
>        Message=Access is denied
>        NativeErrorCode=5
>        Source=System
>        StackTrace:
>             at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
>             at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
>             at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(HttpListener listener, Func`2 appFunc, IList`1 addresses, IDictionary`2 capabilities, Func`2 loggerFactory)
>             at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(Func`2 app, IDictionary`2 properties)
>        InnerException:
> ```

It works if I delete each application after step 3, and then unprovision the application type as well, before F5-deploying again in step 4. Merely deleting each application does not.

**UPDATE:** Rebuilding and F5-deploying seems to work intermittently, but simply F5-deploying doesn't, at least from what I could tell. I also thought for a little while that incrementing the ServiceManifest Version and ApplicationTypeVersion would help, but that didn't work consistently either. The only thing that consistently works is deleting and unprovisioning the application & application type.

I'm running VS 2015 RC as administrator, on Windows 8.1 Pro x64, and the services are .NET 4.5 just like in the tutorial.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? I seem to running into very similar problems

Comment: I haven't seen this problem reappear; for the moment I'm not building any Web API services in SF.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to narrow the problems I was having down to my virus protection. I had two computers with the solution on and one was consistently fine while the other played up all the time. Turning off the virus protection on the one that was playing up seems to have made things a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

The error message here is key: Message=Access is denied.

Usually this means one of two things:

1. The account that your service is running as (Network Service by default) doesn't have access to open a listener on the URL you want. A URL ACL must be set. Service Fabric does this automatically for you when you specify an input endpoint with type HTTP in your ServiceManifest.xml.
2. Some other process is already using the port.

Given that it works the first time you deploy, it's probably not #1. And given that it works when you delete and unprovision the application, I would guess your host process isn't being terminated when you F5 again. When you F5 the second time, can you check to see if your service's service host process is still running?

Comment: No, the old service host process is no longer running when the exception occurs. There is a process running with the same executable name (`webapisf.exe`, the name of the console app -- I assume that's the process you're referring to as the 'service host'), but with a different process ID (PID). That's the one VS is attached to when it catches the exception.

Comment: Otherwise, I would agree wholeheartedly with your analysis. :)

Comment: OK, so you said deleting the application without unprovisioning will cause this problem. Can you try deleting it without unprovisioning and then do two things: 1, see if the service host process is still running, and 2, run netstat -a to see if anything is still hogging that endpoint.

The service host process, btw, is just your service EXE (so whatever you have under "Assembly name" in the service project properties in VS).